# MySQL "IF NOT EXISTS"

Tags: php, mysql

I am having error in SQL syntax but I don't see it.

```
$query        = "IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT id FROM Provider 
                 WHERE name=('$filename') )
                 INSERT INTO Provider (Name) VALUES ('$filename')";

$query_result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
```

The code

```
INSERT INTO Provider (Name) VALUES ('$filename')
```

worked normally if I use just that.

Also the code

```
SELECT id FROM Provider WHERE name=('$filename')
```

worked fine when I tested its value

When I added IF NOT EXISTS I have SQL syntax error but I can't see it!
Any ideas?

Comment: You have syntax error, because you simply can't do that.

Comment: Whats "if not exists" for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `NOT EXISTS` in this context. Try the following query instead:

```sql
INSERT INTO Provider (Name) 
SELECT filename
FROM (SELECT ('$filename') AS filename) AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id 
                  FROM Provider 
                  WHERE name=('$filename')
```

Comment: I have logical error. I see now, actually I don't need to SELECT the id. I have table Providers, and the filename is provider name,  I just want to check if the name is already in the table, if it is not, then to put the record, if not, just to skip. In my case I want to ask if the file name exists in the table already.

Comment: The field of the `SELECT` clause of a `NOT EXISTS` operator, `id` in this case doesn't play any role. You could have used `SELECT 1` instead.